# How to edit a tag name to correctly identify the product it refers too?

Tags: discussion

There is currently a tag

azure-machine-learning

We would like this tag to instead be  azureml.

Is there a way to edit the current tag or do we just have to have a new tag added?

Comment: Who is "we"? Are you representing the project, a group of SO users, or some other group?

Comment: Microsoft team working on AzureML

Answer (score 5):

You can propose a synonym on the [tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-machine-learning/synonyms) when you reach 2500 rep.

Comment: Is there any way to start this process with a rep below 2500?